# Pipe multiple JPG's into an animated GIF using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, stream, animated-gif

I am trying to pipe 5 specific JPG file names into an animated GIF. I have looked through several libraries and found [Gif-Encoder](https://github.com/twolfson/gif-encoder). I am not very good with streams. I cannot seem to figure out how to pipe the RGB result from the [JPEG Decoder](https://github.com/devongovett/jpg-stream) into the addFrame() method of the encoder.

```
function createAnimatedGif(jpgPaths, animatedGifPath) {
    let encoder = new GifEncoder(1280, 720);

    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(animatedGifPath);
    encoder.pipe(writeStream);
    encoder.writeHeader();

    jpgPaths.forEach(filePath => {
        fs.createReadStream(filePath)
            .pipe(new JPEGDecoder)
            //.pipe(encoder);
            //.pipe(pixels => encoder.addFrame(pixels));
    });

    encoder.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is using a read streams a must? I had some success using the module 'get-pixels'.

```
var getPixels = require('get-pixels')
var GifEncoder = require('gif-encoder');
var gif = new GifEncoder(1280, 720);
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('img.gif');
var pics = ['./pics/1.jpg', './pics/2.jpg', './pics/3.jpg'];

gif.pipe(file);
gif.setQuality(20);
gif.setDelay(1000);
gif.writeHeader();

var addToGif = function(images, counter = 0) {
  getPixels(images[counter], function(err, pixels) {
    gif.addFrame(pixels.data);
    gif.read();
    if (counter === images.length - 1) {
      gif.finish();
    } else {
      addToGif(images, ++counter);
    }
  })
}
addToGif(pics);
```

Comment: It works without gif.read()... can you explain the purpose of the gif.read()? Is it necessary? Thanks.

Comment: It's not very well documented in the [gif-encoder documentation](https://github.com/twolfson/gif-encoder), but if you read the documentation for the 'error' event it says
`Emits an Error when internal buffer is exceeded. This occurs when you do not read (either via .on('data') or .read()) and we cannot flush prepared data.`

So while not strictly needed, I was getting errors if I was using to many images without it.